# Hugging 2D object and moving around it

Tags: c#, 2d, collision, unity-game-engine

I have an object generated dynamically into any shape.  It is built using a `LineRenderer` and has an `EdgeCollider` attached.  When a certain object comes into contact with this object I want it to "hug" it and move around it.

If the object is the black line, I would like my object to follow the green line and do a full circle around the object.

[image]

I have read some information about RayCasting and things in the 3D world however being fairly new to Unity I'm not certain how I can do this in 2D.

Any suggestions you have would be very much appreciated, a working example would be appreciated 1000 time more though! ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's incredibly difficult to do this.  Really, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do it in some other fashion, or abandon my idea completely?  I'm not sure saying "Give up" is something any good SO user should be doing... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Just so your aware, there is a 2D equivalent for most of the 3D methods. [Physics2D.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html), instead of Physics.Raycast for example. This is something that is easy to get tripped up on when moving from 3D to 2D in Unity.

As a contract coder I would be willing to build something like this for you. As a stackoverflow user, I'm going to give you an outline you can follow to do it yourself. :)

After collision, start doing this every frame:

1. Rotate your object to face the line.
2. Move your object in the direction you want it to go.
3. Add a force to your object in the direction of the line, to keep it
   pinned against it.

You can use [LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), [Translate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html), and [Rigidbody2D.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) to accomplish this.

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, I'm pretty sure with your suggestion I'm like 80% of the way there already.  In just 20 minutes I've been able to get my object to move along the collider using the `Physics2D.Raycast` function.  Using Velocity, my object appears to speed up on flattened areas for some reason.  I have set it to `IsKinematic`, so no forces should be affecting it... Again, thanks for your help, Do you have any idea why flattened areas would cause a speed up when using: `Velocity = new Vector2(_10 * Time.deltaTime, 0)` - Moving only along the X.

Comment: Try removing friction and bouciness using a physics material. If it's not that, it may need a new question with code posted.

Comment: I see no way of contacting you privately, I'd be interested in perhaps hiring you as a contractor to help me with various bits and pieces of development as I learn Unity if you're interested :)

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention! I was unaware I hadn't added my contact information publicly. You can reach me via my [website](http://atgames.richcodes.com)